# How use vue-loader without vue-cli

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

I am trying to put together the absolute bare minimum example of a Vue project that uses webpack to transpile .vue files.

My goal is to understand each build step in detail. Most tutorials advise to use `vue-cli` and use the `webpack-simple` config. And although that setup works, it seems overkill for my simple purpose. For now I don't want babel, linting or a live web server with hot module reloading.

A minimal example with just `import Vue from 'vue'` works! Webpack compiles the vue library and my own code into one bundle.

But now, I want to add [vue-loader](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/en/) to the webpack config, so that `.vue` files will get transpiled. I have installed vue loader:

```
npm install vue-loader
npm install css-loader
npm install vue-template-compiler
```

And I have added vue-loader to the webpack config:

```
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  entry: './dev/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: {
          loaders: {
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
  }
};
```

I have created hello.vue

```
<template>
  <p>{{greeting}} World</p>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data:function(){
        return {
            greeting:"Hi there"
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

And in my app I import 'hello'

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import hello from "./hello.vue";

    new Vue({
      el: '#app',
      template:`<div><hello></hello></div>`,
      created: function () {   
        console.log("Hey, a vue app!")
      }
    })
```

The loader does not seem to pick up the `.vue` files, I get the error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './hello.js'
```

**EDIT**

When trying to `import hello from 'hello.vue'` I get the error:

```
Unknown custom element: <hello> - did you register the component correctly?
```

Am I missing a step? Am I importing the .vue component the right way? How do I use the hello.vue component from app.js?

Comment: Can you add error?

Comment: Where are you actually trying to import the `.vue` file? And yes, please share the error you're getting.

Comment: I have edited the question, when I try to `import` code from the .vue file this code is not found.

Comment: Yes the insistance on using vue-cli (in their docs) is v annoying. eg I use laravel-mix for .vue compilation and a quick and easy API for webpack.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First, you are not importing the file correctly. You should import it like so:

```
import Hello from './hello.vue'
```

Secondly, after you import the component you'll still need to register it somehow. Either do this globally `Vue.component('hello', Hello)`, or on the Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template:`<div><hello></hello></div>`,
  components: { 'hello': Hello },
  created: function () {   
    console.log("Hey, a vue app!")
  }
})
```

---

As a side note, if you want to be able to import the file without having to specify the `.vue` extension, you can specify that the `.vue` extension should be resolved in your config file.

In that case, the `resolve` object in your config file should look like this:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
  },
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json']
}
```

[Here's the documentation on `resolve.extensions`.](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I missed registering the component with `Vue.component('hello', Hello)`, now it starts to make sense... :)

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @thanksd answer:

As of vue-loader v15, a plugin is required:

```
// webpack.config.js
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // make sure to include the plugin!
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
}
```

https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/

Answer (score 0):

Tagging on some more info here along with @lukebearden and @thanksd. Set up a Vue app from the ground up, it's basic and I tore out some of the styling along the way cause I didn't want to deal with it: but it compiles that JS:

https://github.com/ed42311/gu-vue-app

Can confirm about the plugin, and I haven't added the resolve, but now I will :)

Let me know if you have any thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to register the component to use inside another Vue component. In your example it will be like

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import hello from "./hello.vue";

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template:`<div><hello></hello></div>`,
  components:{hello},
  created: function () {   
    console.log("Hey, a vue app!")
  }
})
```